# Remove Aspect Ratio of Resizable Div Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, aspect-ratio, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a simple div.

```
<div id="resize" style="border:1px solid black"></div>
```

I made it resizeable through [Jquery UI Plugin](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#aspect-ratio). See code below:

```
var w = $('#resize').width();
var h = $('#resize').width();       

$('#resize').resizable({    
    animate: true,
    helper: 'ui-resizable-helper',
    aspectRatio:  w / h
});
```

I want to remove its aspect ratio functionality in run time but still make it resizable. How will I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the [api documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-aspectRatio) there you can read that it could be set after initialization with

```
var myValue = true;
$( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "aspectRatio", myValue );
```

Comment: it should be resizable but the ratio should be free. so it does what the OP asked.

Comment: i am a newbee in stackoverflow. should i remove my comment now that referes to nothing?

Comment: either way, I usually only delete comments when they are actually wrong to avoid confusion later, hence me deleting my original comment :)

Comment: great ! It's up to you buddy. Thanks. +1 for you.

Comment: hey Chris, your answer seems correct but when I tried $('#resize' ).resizable( 'option', 'aspectRatio', false ); . The aspect ratio still continues. Can u kindly point me into right direction. Thanks.

Comment: seems like there is bug. i found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133565/unable-to-apply-jqueryui-resizable-aspectratio-after-initialization-solved). i created an [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2evfe801/) for that. **_aspectRatio** seems to be the object property directly.